# Solved - node.js axios.post part with auth is ok but axios.get after that fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

axios.post part is ok and run into console.log('Authenticated') but
axios.get part fails because of Authorisation required!

```
const axios = require('axios');

webLogin();

function webLogin() {
    var API_SERVER = 'https://a-site-with-api-functions';
    var email = 'myemail';
    var password = 'mypassword';

    axios.post(API_SERVER + '/web/login', { email, password }, { withCredentials: true })
    .then(function(response) {
            //appears every time im running this code, because authentication ist successful
             console.log('Authenticated');
            
            //but following part is failing because of Authorisation required!
             axios.get(API_SERVER + '/api/client/12345678/status', { withCredentials: true })

           }).catch(function(error) {
             console.log('Error on Authentication');
        });
}
```

Comment: this could be an error at the server side

Comment: What do you get back in your authentication response? Are you sure there isn't a token in the response you need to use for future authenticated requests?

Comment: you may need to pass authorisation in case of get, As if you using token based auth, you will get token in response to successful login, same you have to pass so server could identify client based on token

It depends on how you are authorizing user

Answer (score 0):

axios requests are `Promise` and not apply until committed.

try to use `axios.get()` out of previous request.

I think you can use `.finally()` method of axios for your need.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem. webLogin works great, and if OK, calling getstoveValues() and here i always land in catch block and get 401 Authorisation Problem.

```
//vars API_SERVER and so on defined here...

webLogin();


function webLogin() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(API_SERVER + '/web/login', { email, password }, { withCredentials: true });
        // in response steht jetzt die Antwort
        // wenn du sie außerhalb der Funktion nutzen willst:
        // return response; // oder einen Teil davon
        this.log.info('webLogin OK')
        
        //getstoveValues aufrufen, wenn webLogin OK
        getstoveValues();
    } catch (e) {
        // fehler behandeln/loggen
        this.log.error('webLogin' + e.message);
    }
}

function getstoveValues() {
    try {
        const response2 = axios.get(API_SERVER + '/api/client/12345678/status', { withCredentials: true })
        // in response steht jetzt die Antwort
        // wenn du sie außerhalb der Funktion nutzen willst:
        // return response; // oder einen Teil davon
        this.log.info(JSON.stringify(response2.data));
    } catch (e) {
        // fehler behandeln/loggen
        this.log.error('getstoveValues: ' + e.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved - for Node.js i need this:
https://github.com/3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support#usage